# "final" modifier in C and array declaration

Tags: c, arrays, constants

I'm working on a homework assignment for my Intro to C course (don't worry, I don't need you guys to solve anything for me!) and I have a question about design. I'm trying to figure out how to safely set the size of an array by reading input from a file.

Initially I wrote it out like this:

```
fscanf(ifp, "%d", &number_of_pizzas);
float pizza_cost[number_of_pizzas];
```

I'm pretty sure this will build fine, but I know that it's unwise to declare an array with a variable size. My assignment specifies the array can be no bigger than 100, so I know I can just write "pizza_cost[100]", but I'd rather do it precisely instead of wasting the memory.

Java is the language I'm most familiar with, and I believe the solution to the problem would be written out like this:

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
final int i = s.nextInt();
​int[] array =  new int[i];
```

I know C doesn't have a final keyword, so I'm assuming "const" would be the way to go...  Is there any way to replicate that code into C?

Comment: That Java array still have a variable size which is determined at runtime. I don't see a fundamental difference between the two examples. Given that you know the maximum size I would just use that.

Comment: Hm, I don't quite get the point. Are you asking **two** things here? The one is "how to get an array of unknown size without a VLA" to which the answer is `malloc()`. The other thing with `const`; well, I don't understand what the issue is there.

Comment: Your Java-solution uses dynamic allocation (because Java forces you). You can do the same in C, or use a VLA as you did and analyze the maximum stack-usage. (Adding a test before the arrays definition is certainly a good idea.)

Answer (score 2):

> I'm pretty sure this will build fine, but I know that it's unwise to declare an array with a variable size.

That is true only in situations when there is no upper limit on the size. If you know that `number_of_pizzas` is 100 or less, your declaration would be safe on all but the most memory-constrained systems.

If you change your code to validate `number_of_pizzas` before declaring a variable-size array, you would be safe. However, this array would be limited in scope to a function, so you wouldn't be able to return it to your function's caller.

An analogy to Java code would look as follows:

```
float *pizza_cost = malloc(sizeof(float)*number_of_pizzas);
```

Now your array can be returned from a function, but you would be responsible for freeing it at some point in your program by calling `free(pizza_cost)`

As far as making `number_of_pizzas` a `const` goes, it is not going to work with `scanf`: it would be illegal to modify a `const` through a pointer. It is of very little utility even in Java, because you can get the same value by accessing array's `length`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code will build fine.  Running well depends on input values.

I would add just one improvement to this; test the limit of your array initializer before using it:

```
fscanf(ifp, "%d", &number_of_pizzas);
if((number_of_pizzas > MIN_SIZE) &&(number_of_pizzas < MAX_SIZE))//add this test (or something similar)
{
    float pizza_cost[number_of_pizzas];
    //do stuff
}
```

Pick values for MIN_SIZE and MAX_SIZE that make sense for your application...

Doing the same this using dynamic allocation:

```
fscanf(ifp, "%d", &number_of_pizzas);
if((number_of_pizzas > MIN_SIZE) &&(number_of_pizzas < MAX_SIZE))//add this test (or something similar)
{
    float pizza_cost = malloc(sizeof(float)*number_of_pizzas);
    //do stuff
}
```

Don't forget to use `free(pizza_cost);` when you are done.

Answer (score 0):

Any dynamic expression can have a limit placed upon its value easily enough:

```
fscanf(ifp, "%d", &number_of_pizzas);
float pizza_cost[number_of_pizzas > 100 ? 100 : number_of_pizzas];
```

This is not going to be any less safe than using a constant value as long as the bound(s) is/are constant, and has the potential to be smaller should the required number be less.

Making the variable `const`/`final`/anything gains you nothing in this scenario because whether it is modified *after* being used to create the buffer, doesn't affect the size of the buffer in any way.